# How do I sync an object with many items in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have this in Laravel:

```
form: {
    id: null,
    sale_number: 2,
    client: null,
    products: [
        { product_id:"",description: "", quantity: null, price: null }
    ],
},`
```

How to sync many products if `form{}` is the request in model?
I have pivot table `product_sale` with extra fields quantity and price.

I tried this...

```
$items =  $request->products;
$new= [];
foreach( $items as $key => $item){
    $new[$item['product_id']]= array('quantity' => 0,'price'=>0);
}
$sale->products()->sync($new);
```

As example but can't get the `product_id` of every product to sync.

> The error says: "Illegal string offset 'product_id'"

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't $request->products an array of objects? dd($items); before your foreach

Comment: yes it's an array in console appears products as  [{…}, {…}, {…},...]

Comment: with js console log shows form.products when is sent to controller as [{…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) create your sale
>
> 2) create your products
>
> 3) sync them

Something like this:

```
/** @var array $data */
$data = $request->all();

// extract products from the input array
$products = array_get($data, 'products');
unset($data['products']);

$saleModel = \DB::transaction(function() use ($data, $products) {
    $sale = SaleModel::create($data);
    $productModels = [];
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $productModel = ProductModel::create($product);
        $productModels[$productModel->id] = $productModel;
    }

    $productIds = array_keys($productModels);
    $sale->products()->sync($productIds);

    return $sale->fresh();
});
```

Comment: ( in product create shows error :) Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Comment: If $products is just an array of ID's, you don't need the whole foreach loop, and you can just call `$sale->products()->sync($products);`. If not, try `dd($products)` and you should be able to figure it out ;-)